# How can I hide mongoose connection info in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to hide the connection string inside of:

```
mongoose.connect('connection string');
```

In PHP I would create a file called config.php and use define:

```
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
```

Then I would include it into the file I was using it

```
include_once 'path to config.php';
```

I would add this config.php file to the git ignore file to protect the sensitive info.

How can I do this in a node project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file to hold your sensitive info

```
//helper.js
process.env['DB_USERNAME'] = 'username';
process.env['DB_PASSWORD'] = 'password';
```

Then in the file you want to use those values add a require to your sensitive info file:

```
//some_file.js
require '/path/to/helper.js';
```

Comment: I will give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

You could use one or more environment variables and then refer to them, for example:

process.env.DB_USERNAME

To set the environment variable you could throw them into Node when you invoke it:

```
DB_USERNAME='username' DB_PASSWORD='password' node app.js
```

...or you could set them first and then start Node.

```
export DB_USERNAME=username
export DB_PASSWORD=password
```